# how to increase open files on kafka cluster

Tags: linux, apache-kafka, file-descriptor, ambari, hdp

We have 10 kafka machines with kafka version - 1.X

this kafka cluster version is part of HDP version - 2.6.5

We noticed that under `/var/log/kafka/server.log` the following message

```
ERROR Error while accepting connection {kafka.network.Accetpr}
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
```

We saw also additionally

```
 Broker 21 stopped fetcher for partition ...................... because they are in the failed log dir /kafka/kafka-logs {kafka.server.ReplicaManager}
```

and

```
WARN Received a PartitionLeaderEpoch assignment for an epoch < latestEpoch. this implies messages have arrived out of order. New: {epoch:0, offset:2227488}, Currnet: {epoch 2, offset:261} for Partition: cars-list-75 {kafka.server.epochLeaderEpocHFileCache}
```

so regarding to the issue -

```
ERROR Error while accepting connection {kafka.network.Accetpr}
java.io.IOException: Too many open files

how to increase the MAX open files , in order to avoid this issue
```

update:

in ambari we saw the following parameter from `kafka -->  config`

[image]

is this is the parameter that we should to increase?

Comment: 'Too many open files means' the process have run out of available Linux file descriptors. You may have a low limit, or your Kafka may leak file descriptors due to a bug. see this https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/

Comment: Maybe this question is duplicated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52032237/kafka-too-many-open-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
echo "* hard nofile 100000
* soft nofile 100000" | sudo tee --append /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Then you should reboot.

Comment: any other option to update the linits.conf without reboot?

Comment: @jessica I guess not.

Comment: @jessica but maybe you can try this: https://superuser.com/a/1027505

Comment: @jessica i saw the update. It makes sense i think you should try. But i have no idea about ambari sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line to service file of kafka I use (/etc/systemd/system/kafka.service) worked for me. For some reason the service is not using the defined nofile value.

```
LimitNOFILE=100000
```